# windows 7 ip forwarding not work

Tags: windows-7, networking, virtual-machine

i have windows 7 on vmware player and network mode is host only

this vm have two network
1 : 192.168.10.200 for wifi connection
2 : 192.168.220.2 for host only connection to my pc

i have ping in both network correctly

i want connect my pc to wifi connection in vm via ip forwarding in windows 7 on vm

i make enable ip forwarding in registry and started service for that
and add route in my pc for ip address 192.168.10.0 to send to 192.168.220.2

[image]

this is my ipconfig /all command in vm windows 7

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : virtual-PC
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : 
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : Yes
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek RTL8188CU Wireless LAN 802.11n USB 2.0 Network Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : E8-4E-06-26-C3-E9
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::219e:ba78:45c4:5a93%12(Preferred) 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.10.200(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Wednesday, January 18, 2023 7:44:59 AM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, February 24, 2159 2:48:21 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.10.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.10.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 317214214
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-2B-0B-0E-7C-00-0C-29-3A-03-B2
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.10.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-0C-29-3A-03-B2
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::d5b3:1095:d90e:cc77%11(Preferred) 
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.220.2(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.220.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 234884137
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-2B-0B-0E-7C-00-0C-29-3A-03-B2
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{CCCE631F-BC5D-48EA-AFC8-0645CC02118D}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.lan:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 9:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{FBDBD4D2-034B-4CCA-9948-6D3CC96916F2}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #5
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

now when i tracert from my pc for ip 192.168.10.1 this is out :
[image]

this is registry on vm

[image]

and service on vm

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is, other hosts in `192.168.10.0/24` need to have route on them that routes their replies for `192.168.220.1` via `192.168.10.200`.

Certainly that won't be necessary if the original traffics from `192.168.220.1` have been source NAT'd (which AFAIK doesn't come automatically with the enabled IP forwarding and Windows 7 might not offer such possibility at all), or, if `192.168.10.200` is the default gateway on other `192.168.10.0/24` hosts (which apparently can't be the case here).

P.S. Instead of enabling the general IP forwarding with the registry, you might to try [Internet Connection Sharing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Connection_Sharing) instead, which presumes the need for NAT. (See the Limitation section btw; apparently you are somewhat forced to use a specific IP subnet so that the NAT could work, at least before you find out the registry item that allows you to change the subnet it works on. So make sure you update the address and the route on the "pc" accordingly, or enable the DHCP client on it. I'm referring to the virtual network between the vm and the "pc" btw; the physical network of the vm can use any non-conflicting IP subnet. `192.168.10.0/24` should be fine.)

Comment: @John In my comment (on your deleted answer) I implied that I know that "it works" on at least Hyper-V, and very likely on VMware as well, because laymen do not expect what works on Ethernet doesn't "really" works on WiFi, so commercial solutions like them would certainly try be "user-friendly" get it to "work" even if they have to resort to hack, but really if you know "how" it "work", you'll know it's a hack that's worse than NAT. "Generally-speaking" does not refer to how often or even how well it "works" in your or my experience, but whether it's a proper enough / standardized mechanism.

Comment: @John Besides, in the OP's case, even if he wants to attempt / resort to bridging, he would need to set it up on the guest instead of the host / hypervisor. The vm in his case is directly attached to a physical network via a USB-passthrough'd WiFi adapter, and he is trying to share that connect the host to that network via the guest. (The Hyper-V external switch hack for WiFi might not be generally available / applied to "usual" bridging, especially on older system like Windows 7.)

Comment: @John I didn't say *you* have to. (On the contrary, I even explicitly pointed out that you *won't* have to / *aren't supposed* to, because it's a "hack that existed for laymen who do not want to know or care any truth behind the scene".) And to be frank, I'm tired of this. Believe whatever you believe. Yes, it's beautiful world out there. Things work. Peace and love. (Regarding host-only, AFAICT somewhat it just means that "nothing set up out-of-the-box" instead of anything like "not supported" / "isolated" / "secure". But again, you can either do your own digging, or just believe as-is.)

Comment: i reinstall windows 7 and only enable  Internet Connection Sharing (not ip forwarding) and route from 192.168.220.2 (host-only to host os) to 192.168.10.0 (wifi) worked ...